# what is the best way to connect remote mysql database through java/jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, rmi

I have two systems A and B. On system "A" I have mysql database running. On another system "B" i have swing application running which connects to to the remote database on system "A". I have both the systems on same LAN.
How should i connect to that database?

Should I give IP address of system A in database url.
eg.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.20.10:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","root");
```

Will this work properly?
Or
 do i have to use RMI?

Comment: [Yes, it will work properly if you allow remote connection to mysql.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/6099347)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused casue my teacher told me that it may not work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by database on system B?

Of Course you should use JDBC not RMI

Comment: I have installed MySql on system say "B". I want to connect to the database remotely. Means I want to access MySql database from another system...